# Problem rendering 'hello world' in basic Node/Express app

Tags: node.js, express

I'm very new to node but basically, I'm trying to require in my route.js into my app.js file like so

```
var express = require("express"),
app = express(),
routes = require('./routes/index');

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`app is running on ${port}!`))
```

Hers my routes/index.js file:

```
var express = require("express");
var router  = express.Router();

//root route
router.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("hello world");
});
```

The problem is when i go to localhost:3000 i get an error of

> cannot GET /

I can console.log('hi') in my index.js file it shows up in the terminal so I know the file is being pulled in. I'm sure its something simple but no matter what I try it doesn't work.

Also here are the dependencies my package.son file

```
  "dependencies": {
"body-parser": "^1.14.1",
"connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
"cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
"dotenv": "^4.0.0",
"ejs": "^2.3.4",
"express": "^4.13.3",
"express-session": "^1.11.3"
}
```

I'll pull in the rest of them after I fix this bug.

Comment: Yeah I did both :/

Comment: You need to tell Express to use the routes  app.use(routes);

Comment: Yeah I remember seeing that on the express docs but when I tried it I got this error: app.use() requires a middleware function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your *app.js* needs to actually use the routes using `app.use()`.

**app.js**

```
var express = require("express");
var routes = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use('',routes);
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`app is running on ${port}!`));
```

...and your *routes.js* `router` needs to be exported so it can be used as a require in *app.js*.

**./routes/index.js**

```
var express = require("express");
var router  = express.Router();

//root route
router.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("hello world");
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: I literally figured this out at the same time you posted the answer haha. Thank you regardless.